# Replace value that does not equal specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried looking at other similar questions but haven't found an adequate answer for my needs.

I have a data frame with a column `answer` where respondents can answer `yes`, `no`, `maybe`, or some other response. The some other response is free text and for my purposes, I just need to categorize it as `other` but I can't quite figure out how to replace a value in a pandas dataframe that does not equal a few different values (I've seen answers for replacing values that do not equal one value, but I don't want it to effect the rows with yes, no, and maybe).

Sample data frame is below, any help is appreciated.

```
id | answer |
1  | Yes    |
2  | Maybe  |
3  | No     |
4  | idk    |
5  | wtf    |
6  | wth    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with your condition

```
df['new_answer'] = df['answer'].where(df['answer'].isin(['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe']), 'other')

   id answer new_answer
0   1    Yes        Yes
1   2  Maybe      Maybe
2   3     No         No
3   4    idk      other
4   5    wtf      other
5   6    wth      other
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [*categorical data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) :

```
cats = pd.Categorical(df["answer"], categories=["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "other"])

df["answer"] = pd.Series(cats).fillna("other")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   id answer
0   1    Yes
1   2  Maybe
2   3     No
3   4  other
4   5  other
5   6  other
```